# Site template with default column values?

Tags: site, default-value, hidden, template

Our users need to be able to create sites that contains several lists with some pre-defined values to ease data entry. Preferrably those values should be hidden managed metadata fields but also other kinds of fields would be ok.

I have created a site template that contains lists with some default column values but the default values do not get passed to any sites that are created with the template. Is it not possible to pass default values from a site template?